# write rspec test based on age or date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, testing, rspec

I have a method that should return a category of member based on the age/date_of_birth. I want do write some test for that method because it a important method.

And my question is how can I test the model in order not failing the test in future because the date continuously changing.

I try to provide a pseudo test:

```
IF THE member IS > 18 => OUTPUT: "Adult"  
IF THE member IS < 15 => OUTPUT: "XYZ"
```

thanks

Answer (score 4):

Use [timecop](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop) gem to freeze time in spec or [TimeHelpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Testing/TimeHelpers.html) from Rails 4.2 for the same things (see `travel` method).

Comment: thanks for the time helpers, didn't know about them being native now

Answer (score 1):

Do you even need to manipulate time? you can simply set the member's birthdate to the past

```
# build member
let(:adult_member) { Member.new(date_of_birth: 20.years.ago) }
let(:young_member) { Member.new(date_of_birth: 13.years.ago) }

# spec
expect(adult_member.whatever).to eq('Adult')
expect(young_member.whatever).to eq('Young')
```

Comment: @willis thanks I have combined your both solutions :) I have use timecop and I think your solution with  (20.years.ago) is also nice.